# Graph and Number theory

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory

[image]

We have two groups of nodes, group A consisting of N items, group B
consisting of M items. There is an edge connecting node $a$ of group A and node $b$ of group B,
where 
$$a = i \mod N$$ 
$$b = i \mod M$$
where i is an integer.

We need to find for each node if there is a path connecting to another node in the graph.

As I am a CS guy, I love brute force. To create the adjacency matrix,
I iterated from $i$ from $0$ to $LCM(N, M)$, since after that, we would
get same edge pairs. Now, discarding this approach, how can one find mathematically, if two nodes of the graph are connected by a path or not?

Comment: Nop, you can take any values of i, and you need to find which nodes of two groups can be connected. I have a picture, please upvote this topic.

Comment: I am not sure the question is so clear. What is $A$ exactly? Any set of integers? Are they distinct? Or is $A=\{0,\ldots,N-1\}$ as in your examples?

Comment: a is the index of node in group A and b is the index of node in group B. Indexing starts from 0 as shown in the picture. for group A, 0 <= a < N and for group B 0 <= b < M

Comment: I understand that, but can $A$ be any set of integers, or is $A$ always the numbers from $0$ to $N-1$?

Comment: We are given the total count of nodes in group A which is equal to N and total count of nodes in group B which is equal to M. Nodes in group A are numbered from 0 to N - 1 and in group B from 0 to M - 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can readily show:

> Node $x$ (from $A$ or $B$) is connected to node $y$ (from $A$ or $B$) iff $x\equiv y\pmod{\gcd(N,M)}$

Here's a sketch:

The group $\mathbb Z$ acts on the graph as follows: If $k\in \mathbb Z$, then the action maps vertex $a\in A$ to $a+k\bmod N\in A$ and vertex $b\in B$ to vertex $b+k\bmod M\in B$. This works because an edge $(a,b)$ that is witnessed by the integer $i$ with $a\equiv i\pmod N$, $b\equiv i\pmod M$ becimes the edge $(a+k\bmod N,b+k\bmod M)$ witnessed by $i+k$.

By this action we conclude: If $a_1,a_2\in A$ then the existence of a path from $a_1$ to $a_2$ depends only on $a_2-a_1\pmod N$.

Let $I$ be the set of integers $k$ such that there exists a path for some pair $(a_1,a_2)$ with $a_2-a_1\equiv k\pmod N$. (As just seen "for some pair" implies "for all pairs").

- $I$ is not empty, for example clearly $N\in I$ and $M\in I$.
- If $k\in I$ then also $-k\in I$ (just interchaneg $a_1$ and $a_2$)
- If $k_1,k_2\in I$ then $k_1+k_2\in I$ (just concatenate two paths).

It follows that $I$ is an ideal in $\mathbb Z$ and contains $N$ and $M$, hence is of the form $I=d\mathbb Z$ with $d\mid\gcd(N,M)$.
But $d$ cannot be a properdivisor of $\gcd(N,M)$ because for every single edge $(a,b)$ with $a\equiv i\pmod N$ and $b\equiv i\pmod M$ we have that $a\equiv i\equiv b\pmod{\gcd(N,M)}$.
So far we have

> If $x,y\in A$ then they are connected iff $x\equiv y\pmod{\gcd(N,M)}$

By symmetry, we also have

> If $x,y\in B$ then they are connected iff $x\equiv y\pmod{\gcd(N,M)}$

To also treat the case when $x\in A$, $y\in B$ (or vice versa) note that the first edge from $x$ to a vertex in $B$ (or vice versa) connects vertices that are congruent modulo $\gcd(N,M)$.

Comment: Yep this is what the result is. But, I couldn't prove myself. Some hints

Comment: I had found the answer, but not the way to the answer. So, I tried for small problems by using brute force to create adjacency matrix and then running depth first search / bfs to find if there is path from one node to another. Actually I am not a math guy. So any intuitions regarding this problem would be really helpful

Comment: $a1 \equiv i \pmod N, a2 \equiv i + k \pmod N, a2 - a1 \equiv k \pmod N $, what do you mean by the statement that, the existence of path from a1 to a2 depends only on $a2 - a1 \pmod N$. I didn't understand this.

Comment: So far I understood that, $N \in I$ and $M \in I$, implies $gcd(N, M) \in I$. Also, for some d, all numbers in I are divisible by d. Since, $gcd(N, M) \in I$, it must also be divisible by d and d must be equal to gcd(N, M).