# unique floor value proof

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove that $\lfloor \frac{n}{i}\rfloor - \lfloor \frac{n}{i+1}\rfloor 
\ge 1$, if $i \le \lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$ and $1 \le i \le n$

I think I had seen the proof somewhere in this website, but I can't find correct keywords to search the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\left\lfloor\frac{n}i\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{i+1}\right\rfloor\ge 1\tag{1}$$

if and only if there is an integer $m$ such that

$$\frac{n}{i+1}<m\le\frac{n}i$$

or, equivalently, such that

$$mi\le n<m(i+1)\;.\tag{2}$$

Suppose that $1\le i\le\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor$, and let $m=\left\lfloor\frac{n}i\right\rfloor$. Then

$$mi=\left\lfloor\frac{n}i\right\rfloor i\le n\;.$$

Moreover, $\frac{n}i<m+1$, so

$$n<(m+1)i=mi+i\le mi+\sqrt{n}=mi+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}\le mi+\frac{n}i\;,$$

and since $mi+i$ is an integer we must have

$$n<mi+i\le mi+\left\lfloor\frac{n}i\right\rfloor=mi+m=m(i+1)\;.$$

Thus, $(2)$ holds, and therefore $(1)$ holds.

Comment: Nice proof. Thank you!

Comment: @nitrogen: You’re welcome!

Comment: Hi, I have one problem that has been bugging me, can you manage some time any time you want so that we can discuss on chat(problem is related to number theory, I had posted the same question here, but I don't understand the answer).

Comment: @nitrogen: Can you give me a link to the question here? I’ll be going to bed pretty soon, but that way I can at least take a quick look now.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324821/graph-and-number-theory

Comment: I also tried another way to prove, $m(i + 1) \ge i(m+1)$ implies $m \ge i$, implies $\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\rfloor \ge i$ and thus $\frac{n}{i} \ge i$, implies $i^2 \le n$

Comment: Looks like I cannot prove $i \le \lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$ from $i \le \sqrt n$

Comment: @nitrogen: That follows from the fact that $i$ is an integer: $\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor$ is the *largest* integer less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$, so if $i$ is an integer less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$, then $i$ can be at most $\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor$. (I am off to bed now, but I’ve opened a tab with the other question and will take a look tomorrow.)