# Corectness of Prime Factorization over a range

Tags: algorithms, factoring

Here is an algorithm for counting the total prime factors of all positive natural numbers $\le N$.

Initially $f_{i} = 1$ for all $1 \le i \le N$

```
loop i from 2 to N
    if f[i] = 1 then
        loop j from 2 to N
            f[j * i] = f[i] + f[j]
    endif
```

Is the algorithm correct? If so why?

Well I checked where the algorithm could fail
if i = 2, then f[2 * 15] = f[2] + f[15]
But f[15] = 1, since $i \lt 15$.
But eventually f[30] = f[5 * 6] = f[5] + f[6].
The result becomes correct.

Comment: You can probably prove this using a loop invariant. It seems that after each outer iteration for the variable i, f[k] contains for all k either 1, if k is prime, or the number of prime factors within the range 1...i otherwise.

Comment: I need to prove that the last  f[j * i] = f[i] + f[j] is the correct one, which implies f[i] is correct and f[j] is also correct.

Comment: Note that `f[m]` is last written (if ever, that is, if `m` is composite) when `i` is the largest prime factor of `m`. Using that, it's an easy induction proof.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I don't get it. Would you please write the induction proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof:

1) Let $p(n)$ be the number of prime factors of $n \in \mathbb{N}, n\ge 2$. The algorithm uses the basic fact from number theory, that $p(m \cdot n) = p(m) + p(n)$.

2) In each iteration of the outer loop, $i$ is a prime if and only if $f[i]=1$. If this is not clear to you, check out the proof of the Sieve of Eratosthenes. While in the Sieve of Eratosthenes numbers usually are flagged as being composite by setting a boolean flag, this algorithms "flags" the numbers by assigning a value greater than 1 to the according field in the array $f$.

3) As it's easy to see, the algorithm overwrites some fields in $f$ many times. So if we are interested in the correctness of the final result of the alogorithm, we have to see, which value is finally assigned to a field of $f$. For any field $k \in \{2, ..., N\}$ this happens exactly when the loop variables $i$ and $j$ are so that $i \cdot j = k$ and $i$ is the largest prime factor of $k$. This is what Daniel mentioned in his comment, and it follows from 2).

Now we prove by induction: $\forall k \in \{2, ..., N\}: f[k] = p(k)$ after the algorithm terminates.

For $k=2$ this is clear.

Let's assume that it is true for $2, ..., k-1$. Let $i,j$ be the indices of the loops when $f[k]$ becomes finally assigned, so we have $i \cdot j = k$. As stated in 3), $i$ is the largest prime factor of $k$. In the following we want to show that $f[j]$ has already been finally assigned and that $f[j] = p(j)$.

Since $j$ is a divisor of $k$, all prime factors of $j$ are less or equal $i$. Let $t \le i$ be the largest prime factor of $j$. Then we have two cases:

$t < i$: In the $i$-th iteration of the outer loop we've already passed the $t$-th iteration. So because of 3), $f[j]$ has already been assigned to it's final value.

$t = i$: Let $z \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $j = i \cdot z$. $i$ is the largest prime factor of $j$, so $j$ becoms also finally assigned in the $i$-th iteration of the outer loop, but in the $z$-th iteration of the inner loop. Because of $z < j$, we have already passed the $z$-th iteration of the inner loop, when we are in the $j$-th iteration of the inner loop. So $f[j]$ has already been assigned to it's final value.

Because of $j < k$ and the induction hypothesis, we know $f[j] = p(j)$. So using 1) we get

$f[k] = f[i]+f[j] = p(i)+p(j) = p(i \cdot j) = p(k)$.

This shows, that the algorithm assigns the correct value to $f[k]$.

q.e.d.

Don't hesitate to ask for clarification if anything is unclear.

By the way, this is a very interesting algorithm that obviously runs in $O(N\cdot Primes(N))$, where $Primes(N)$ is the number of prime numbers within $2, ..., N$. As far as I know, there are good small estimates for $Primes(N)$ in number theory. So this seems to be very efficient, though I don't know whether there is a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: 2 will cross all multiples of 2 and the answer is valid for all composites containing only 2 as prime factor. So $2^k$ is valid for $i = 2$. The incorrect ones are the ones that contain prime number large than 2. Now consider 3, since all composites of form $2^k$ is valid, $3^x 2^k$ will also be valid. Continuing the process, we see that all factorization is correct. Am I right?

Comment: This seems to be a good intuitive explaination of the algorithm, though it is not a complete proof. For example you say (as I understand it), that after the first iteration of the outer loop, which is for $i=2$, $f$ contains the correct result for all multiples of 2. This is non trivial and might need to be proven.

Comment: No, I didn't mean correct results for all multiples of two. I clearly meant correct multiples of the form $2^k$

Comment: I see. So as I understand, you want to prove that after the $i$-th iteration of the outer loop the results are correct for $f[k]$ if $k$'s prime factors are smaller or equal to $i$. Seems to be an idea for an alternative proof. You will also need induction then.

Comment: Yes exactly. By the way, can u help me on my previous problem about number theory on a graph. It would be nice if you'd explain what you can understand. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324821/graph-and-number-theory/1324828#1324828